# What is the best way to write independent programs in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently in 1st semester of CS, and I find that Visual Studio is a much more elegant solution to C++ programming than DevC++ or Code::Blocks, I think i'm going to use it much more in the future. The types of programs I write are mostly independent of each other, because I have not yet learned object orientation.
Problem is, Visual Studio is much more difficult for independent programs. I just started trying to learn my way through it, but haven't yet found a way to easily create independent source files. I tried creating a project and putting multiple files in "source files" folder, but that generates a lot of trouble, the files seems to conflict with each other and generate some errors, like this one

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
>
> error LNK2005: _main already defined in whatever.obj

Also, not putting files inside "source files" generates some problems too. This is one example of the type of code I write regularly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int m, n;
cin >> m >> n;
int a[150][150];
int b;
cin >> b;
int x1, y1;

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
{
    cin >> x1 >> y1;
    a[x1][y1] = -1;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == -1)
        {
            if (a[i - 1][j - 1] != -1)  a[i - 1][j - 1]++;
            if (a[i - 1][j] != -1)  a[i - 1][j]++;
            if (a[i - 1][j + 1] != -1)  a[i - 1][j + 1]++;
            if (a[i][j - 1] != -1)  a[i][j - 1]++;
            if (a[i][j + 1] != -1)  a[i][j + 1]++;
            if (a[i + 1][j - 1] != -1)  a[i + 1][j - 1]++;
            if (a[i + 1][j] != -1)  a[i + 1][j]++;
            if (a[i + 1][j + 1] != -1)  a[i + 1][j + 1]++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == 0)
            cout << "-";
        else if (a[i][j] > 0)
            cout << a[i][j];
        else
            cout << "B";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated to help me with this problem!

Comment: Create a new solution for each new project.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio there's the concept of '`Solutions`' and '`Projects`'.

- '`Solutions`' contain **zero or more** '`Projects`'.
- '`Projects`' contain **zero or more** files (e.g. *.cpp, *h).

A single program would usually have its own project.

A solution usually is a set of programs or libraries that work together to solve a task, but they could also be completely unrelated so that's for you to decide.

Generally to solve your problem with colliding files you would simply create a new project:

- `File -> New -> Project`.

Comment: Isn't there a faster way to create unrelated programs without having to create a new project?

Comment: Believe me having two different programs in one project will not make you happy. Also creating a new project is quite fast. The only way for you to keep two programs in one project would be to ensure that your source files are not colliding by for example using namespaces and then you would need to either comment out the other entry point (int main()) or mess with the entry point setting in the linker, which is certainly something you want to avoid.